# PHP - json_decode not working when through a curl request

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

I have a PHP array on the source file - source.php; and I am converting it to a json through `$ouput = json_encode($ouput);`. The `$output` variable is already an array.

```
$ouput = json_encode($ouput);
echo  '<pre>';
print_r($ouput);
echo  '</pre>';
```

The json displays well when I call it on my destination file using cURL as a json encoded string. However, when I want to convert the string to PHP array nothing gets displayed.

```
$displayReturns = curl_exec($curl);
curl_reset($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$displayReturns = json_decode($displayReturns,true);
print_r($displayReturns);
```

Comment: Can you send us the json output?

Comment: `var_dump($displayReturns)` check what r u getting, and share the result.

Comment: Did you check for errors `echo json_last_error_msg()`

Comment: @pr1nc3 - without the json docode it would appear as `{"user-data":{"user":"hello-com-01","client":"43cb6a1a17a15f2fdc641e935ea1c9467f5d742b107c6798d"}}`

Comment: i tried and its working fine `json_decode('{"user-data":{"user":"hello-com-01","client":"43cb6a1a17a15f2fdc641e935ea1c9467f5d742b107c6798d"}}',true)`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Its telling me `Syntax error`

Comment: Then you JSON is not well formed for some reason

Comment: @devpro Could it be because there is other data in the source page that is being captured by json_decode that isn't allowing it to be converted? Could this be from the CURL?

Comment: That is very probably it

Comment: `curl_reset($curl);
curl_close($curl);` move them at last

Comment: It would be useful to see EXACTLY what is returned from that CURL Call. There is obviously something else in the response as what you show works just fine

Comment: `{"user-data":{"user":"hello-com-01","client":"43cb6a1a17a15f2fdc641e935ea1c9467f5d742b107c6798d"}}` is it CURL response??

Comment: @devpro that is the curl responsense. I'm not sure whether its because the source is calling the output through `print_r($ouput);` and I'm capturing something else.

Comment: so its means, curl giving u correct response. `curl_reset($curl);
curl_close($curl);` move these two lines after json_deocde line and chk

Comment: @devpro - I did still same reply. My suspicion is that `print_r($ouput);` from the source is returning something else besides the json string.

Comment: What happened to your JSON ERROR Msg

Comment: It tells me `Syntax error`

Comment: Then there is still something in the curl response you are not showing us. Please do a `echo $displayReturns;` after the `curl_exec()` and post that to your question

Comment: @RiggsFolly without the json_decode I get `{"user-data":{"user":"hello-com-01","client":"43cb6a1a17a15f2fdc641e935ea1c9467f5d742b107c6798d"}` with the json_decode I get nothing.

Comment: Grasping at straws here. try to do a `$displayReturns = trim($displayReturns);` before giving it to json_decode

Comment: var_dump also shows you the byte length of the variable content. The JSON you have shown does not contain anything outside of the lower ASCII range - so that should be 98 bytes in nearly any encoding imaginable. So, which length did var_dump show you …?

Comment: So where did we get to on this then?

Comment: I did trim but still nothing. I think when I'm doing a cURL request its getting white space from the previous page that is invalidating the json_decode.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: My source file had the following:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r $ouput;
echo '<pre>';
```

Once I removed them everything worked fine.